# Can not run Gwget Download Manager

Tags: 11.04, downloads

I use ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal. I was searching for download manager and I found Gwget Download Manager as highly recommended Download Manager for ubuntu. I have installed it from Software Center which is 1.0.4. Now the problem is I can only run this one time if I close Gwget and try to run it again it never shows up. If I logout and try after logging in again I can run it for the first time then it does not start. How do I get rid of this problem?

Comment: My answer may not be answer to your question but what I feel is Gwget is not proper download manger. Does it support multi-thread downloading. If you are looking for a good download manager, check out : jdownload manager.

Comment: @Abhijeet hmm I'll give a try to JDownloader. Does it support Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: It does support firefox through one plugin, which it will install automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you opened for the first time and close it , it will not get closed but still remain in background (an icon will appear in the top panel in that case). So click on that icon to get it back to foreground instead of opening gwget again. (Actually I am not very sure. I remember it vaguely)

PS : Try multiget - A superb download manager :)

Comment: when I hit Close button the process still remain unkilled in process list. May be it is a bug, isn't it?

Comment: Does MultiGet support chrome and firefox?

Comment: Yes exactly, close button for this application doesnt kill the process but instead just sends it to background with an icon on the top panel. Hence it will not be killed. Its not a bug but a feature

Comment: Check this for multiget integration - http://geekwentfreak.wordpress.com/2009/11/15/integrating-multiget-into-firefox/

Comment: Even jdownload manager is good :)

Comment: ya it appears in the top panel(in gnome) but as I use 11.04 as it comes with Unity so I can not find tray like icon in top panel(of Unity). So How to make it appear on top panel(of Unity)? or how i can get it back to foreground in Unity after I minimize it?